# Search database table with all special characters

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, hibernate

I have a table of project in which i have a project name and that project name may contain any special character or any alpha numeric value or any combination of number word or special characters.

Now i need to apply keyword search in that and that may contain any special character in search.

So my question is: How we can search either single or multiple special characters in database?

I am using mysql 5.0 with java hibernate api.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with some simple sanitization of you query.

e.g: a search for `\@(%*#$\` becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE name LIKE "%\\@(\%*#$\\%";
```

when evaluated the back slashes escape so that the search ends up being anything that contains `"\@(%*#$\"`

In general anything that's a special character in a string can be escaped via a backslash.  This only really becomes tricky if you have a name such as: `"\\foo\\bar\\"` which to escape properly would become `"\\\\foo\\\\bar\\\\"`

A side note, please proof read your posts prior to finalizing.  Its really depressing and shows a lack of effort when your questions title has spelling errors in it.